# Where should I go to learn Set Theory?

Tags: set-theory

I heard somewhere that set theory is kind of (or pretty much (I don't remember)) the foundation of modern math, so I wanted to learn some of it. I went to the Wikipedia page and was pretty daunted. I also couldn't find much on YouTube.

Comment: Yes, it is the "basic language" of modern mathematics. You can easily learn it using textbooks: e.g. [Enderton](https://docs.ufpr.br/~hoefel/ensino/CM304_CompleMat_PE3/livros/Enderton_Elements%20of%20set%20theory_%281977%29.pdf)

Comment: If you read the Wikipedia entry for Set Theory, it lists half a dozen books under "Further Reading". After you have worked through these you may have an idea of a first glimpse.

Comment: *and was pretty daunted* --- You don't say anything about your mathematical background, which makes it nearly impossible for anyone to give you advice. That said, if Enderton's book and those at its level are too much for you at this time, try [**Introduction to the Theory of Sets**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486453103) by Joseph Breuer -- doesn't require calculus, but probably roughly at the same "math level" as calculus. And if Breuer's book seems too advanced for you, maybe [**Sets**](https://archive.org/details/setsadle00adle) by Irving Adler and Ruth Adler -- early high school level.

Comment: I'm pretty comfortable with calculus, algebra, geometry, and trigonometry. I also know a bit of linear algebra.